# Effectively Using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have an app written with C#. I have a collection of objects and I need to perform tasks like sorting and jumping to a page of the objects. Currently, I have something that looks like this:

```
this.Items = model.Items
  .Where(x => x.Id > 0)
  .ToList();

if (SortBy == "Name")
{
  if (Direction == "Descending")
    this.Items = (this.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name)).ToList();
  else
    this.Items = (this.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Name)).ToList();
}
else if (SortBy == "Description")
{
  if (Direction == "Descending")
    this.Items = (this.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Description)).ToList();
  else
    this.Items = (this.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Description)).ToList();
}

// I want to jump to the second page
this.Items = this.Items.Skip(26).ToList();
```

Is there a better way to do this? All of the `ToList` calls seem like that would be performance draining. Maybe I'm wrong though.

Thanks!

Comment: `All of the ToList calls seem like that would be performance draining.`.  That's quite right.  Given that you know this, and have no reason to add them, why are they there?

Comment: How is defined `Items`?

Comment: You wouldn't need `ToList` if `this.Items` was an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a `List<T>`

Comment: what do you do with the items ? take a look at collection view source if you are binding this to xaml

Comment: You can avoid calling ToList() everywhere. Here it acts as a greedy operator and makes the LINQ execute there itself and here it makes no sense. It can carry out a deferred execution and at the last statement call the ToList() to get the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer calling `.ToList` until your last line since based on your logic it always runs.  Interim logic builds upon an IQueryable.  Whether or not ToList has a significant impact largerly depends on whether this is Linq2Objects or it is Linq2SQL/Entitity Framework/Some other Database ORM.  With database ORMs typically each .ToList hydrates the list and results in a database query executed.  For Linq2Objects there is still a performance cost, but no where near the magnitude involved in a database call.

```
// itemsQuery will be of type IQueryable or IEnumerable depending on type of Items
var itemsQuery = model.Items.Where(x => x.Id > 0);

if (SortBy == "Description")
{
  // we'll chain additional criteria or sorts to the IQueryable,
  // and update the query reference by assigning over the previous itemsQuery variable
  if (Direction == "Descending")
    itemsQuery  = itemsQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.Description);
  else
    itemsQuery  = itemsQuery.OrderBy(x => x.Description);
}

// I want to jump to the second page
this.Items = itemsQuery.Skip(26).ToList();
```

Essentially you are dynamically building up a query, but not actually running the query until the end where you call ToList, which will essentially build an SQL query from the expression tree and execute the entire chained sequence of `.Where(...).OrderBy(...).Skip(26).ToList`

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right that all of the `ToList` calls are a major problem.  Not only are they forcing all of the work to be done in the client if the underlying data source represents a database query provider, but even if it is inherently a LINQ to objects query you're needlessly creating, populating, and discarding lists.  You're also removing any ability for deferred execution.  Since you're not actually getting anything out of those calls, you can simply remove them all.

Next, you can write a method to create a selector, so that you don't need to duplicate all of that code for each column you sort on:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, TResult>> CreateSelector<T, TResult>(
    string memberName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, memberName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(body, param);
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
IQueryable<Item> items = model.Items;
if (Direction == "Descending")
    items = items.OrderByDescending(CreateSelector<Item, string>(SortBy));
else
    items = items.OrderBy(CreateSelector<Item, string>(SortBy));
items = items.Skip(26);
```

If the underlying data source that you have is an `IEnumerable`, not an `IQueryable`, just change the type of `Items` and `Compile` the selector expression.